# Magento 2.0 Default Product Search Results To A List View

Tags: magento2, search, magento-2.0

How do I display product search results in a single column? Essentially I want to default it to a list view all the time. Would I need to make a controller to append the query variable to the URL?

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 3):

To be precise, add below code to layout of the module:

```
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="_current_grid_mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

To set default list mode for search result page, you can copy **catalogsearch_result_index.xml**

from:

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\view\frontend\layout
```

to:

```
app\design\frontend\Your_Vendor_Name\Your_Theme_Name\Magento_CatalogSearch\layout
```

add this code:

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="_current_grid_mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
</arguments>
```

into block name: **product_list_toolbar**